# How do I limit ruby's CPU usage for Passenger/NGINX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, nginx, passenger

I'm running Passenger on Nginx for my Ruby on Rails apps.

My app occasionally runs some very intensive processes that max the ruby processes CPU out at 100% while processing for up to 30 seconds at a time.

I want to be able to limit the available CPU that my ruby processes have access to.

Passenger and NGINX are setup fine, I simply need to limit the available CPU that my passenger/ruby processes can access.

If I can set this to 80% per process, then my intensive process will take a little longer to process (maxed out at 80%), but my total CPU won't be maxed out at 100%, leaving CPU for other processes to access.

Is there a Linux config/application that can do this?

Comment: Why not determine what is actually using up that much CPU? Maybe it's a CPU-intensive task that shouldn't be run during the request?

Best way going about doing that is looking at logs when your CPU usage spikes and determining what was the last request/action _or_ simply clicking around the site until you hit that exception

Comment: I know what is using the CPU, it's the ruby process when exporting/processing a huge amount of data.  The request has to run and it takes a long time to process (only runs a couple of times a day at most), I just want to allow it to run, but only allow it to use 80% of available CPU.

Comment: Do you know what google.com is? Just first search results http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups

Answer (score 0):

Turning my follow-up comment into an answer. You can probably use the link supplied by Alexander to limit the CPU.

However, this is a bad architectural approach. In Rails land, CPU-intensive, and long-running tasks are usually done in a background job. Examples of tasks like this include exporting/processing amounts of data, sending e-mails, making third-party API calls triggered by user action.

So, what I advise is that you set up a background job system. You can use Sidekiq, for example. The request that kicks off "exporting/processing huge amounts of data" simply enqueues a job that is picked up by a worker process and done. This way, you can scale that worker process (or a group of them) separately from your Nginx/Passenger setup. If you need to give that process more CPU or less has nothing to do with your web layer. Same goes for memory.

If you serve this data to the browser or whatever, you also have options. You can store this file on S3 and return a link to it. You can store it locally in a path accessible to nginx and allow nginx to serve it as any other file by again providing a link. If it takes 30 seconds to generate a response, you can either e-mail that link to the user *or* hook up a short-lived websocket and push the link to the data over it.

I hope you can consider this approach as an alternative to limiting CPU usage of your web processes.